# How to extract content between tags in html using grep command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sed, grep, computer-forensics

I want to write a grep command which will extract content between h1 tags irrespective of class and other attributes

I tried

```
 grep -o '>.*</h1>' Email.txt
```

But gave only three elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU `grep`, you may use

```
grep -oP '<h1(?:\s[^>]*)?>\K.*?(?=</h1>)' Email.txt
```

The `-P` option will enable PCRE regex engine and the pattern will match

- `<h1` - `<h1` string
- `(?:\s[^>]*)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of a whitespace (`\s`) followed with 0+ chars other than `>`
- `>` - a `>` char
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far from the match memory buffer
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=</h1>)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with `</h1>` substring.